# Unit Testing for MVC project in Orchard

Tags: unit-testing, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard CMS for my MVC application. I need to implement Unit testing for the same. Can anyone help me with the implementation guide for this?

Regards,
Chandana

Comment: Did you look at the existing tests?

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for creating test cases for my Custom content types. Any help on that?

Comment: Sure. Care to share a scenario that you'd like to test? This is really very vague. Also, please look at the Tests and Specs folders under the Orchard solution.

Comment: We've created ContentType (say "Footer") in Orchard CMS site, consisting of ContentFields (Text, ContentPicker, MoviePicker) and ContentParts. I need to test the Get method, that retrieves the "Footer" from the Orchard CMS database. But, problem is that, there is not way to connect to this database in Test Module project (Orchard.Tests.Modules). I can intantiate IOrchardService and ContentManager, but they are empty and not connected to my site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that is not unit testing. I'm not sure I see the point of testing the data access of Orchard, that already has abundant tests in place. Instead, you should be testing what is specific to your code, mocking, faking or stubbing the underlying infrastructure. There are also plenty of examples of that in the existing tests. You can also look at the tests in this module for examples: https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.commerce/src/c88a2c033e4f6cc8ee1f619ab149d7f1460e93ba/Nwazet.Commerce.Tests?at=default